# Server hard disk read speed and client download speed, is there a connection?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, bandwidth, bottleneck

Ok so a client's download speed is only as fast as a server's upload speed, and vice versa. Based on the answers to this post:

[Does upload speed depend upon download speed of the server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/234201/does-upload-speed-depend-upon-download-speed-of-the-server)

In other words, the data transfer rate between the two computers is only as fast as the speed of the "bottleneck".

Let's pretend the two computers are in two different networks and both have 100Mbps internet connection. Ben wants a copy of a file in Mark's computer hard disk with 30Mbps read speed. Does this mean that Ben can download the file at a speed of around 30Mbps only, despite having an internet connection faster than 30Mbps?

Comment: We don't do homework for people, especially from those that haven;'t even read our FAQ, go away.

Comment: LOL The fact that I made this simple doesn't mean this is a homework. Does it really have to be technical? It's summer vacation here in the Philippines. :)

Comment: Think pipes: there is no way that water can come out of the pipe faster (volume rate) than it goes into the pipe. This is true for any subsection of the pipe. So everything downstream of the bottleneck can only go at the bottleneck speed.

Comment: Negative vote? I had a hard time searching Google, that's why I posted it here, as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, yes. There might be bursts faster than that if data is cached in memory on the server. But assuming the client keeps accessing different data, eventually the rate will drop to 30Mbps and the disk will be the limiting factor.

Comment: hmmm...about the cache, I was thinking about that too. But what if the data is too big to be cached "whole"? Can the server cache the half of it, for example? And if so, will only the first half be uploaded at a speed > 30Mbps?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the server. It might well be designed to hold specific, selected objects in memory. Or it might not.